# ng-show/hide delayed with image animation

Tags: javascript, css, image, angularjs, css-animations

So my page has 2 buttons, that use ng-click to render a image specific to each.

image 1 is displayed when the page loads, and the animation bringing the image into view works fine.

switching to image 2 (via button 2) works fine. the animation pulls image 2 into view

But upon clicking button 1, to display image 1, there is a problem.  The image initially pulled onto the page on clicking button 1 is image 2, and right around when ng-hide is applied to image 2, image 2 fades out and image 1 is now displayed, and appears to have been sitting behind it.

Anyone have advice or an idea to what this problem may be?  I have been looking through resources online, and haven't seen anything that is exactly like this.

- Note: this only happens for the transition from image 2 to image 1, not image 1 to image 2.

-edit, here is my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div ng-repeat='image in images'>
        <div class="{{image.cls}} select" ng-click="showThis($index)" value="{{image.set}}">
            <label>{{image.title}}</label>
        </div>
        <img ng-show="nowShowing==$index" class="slidedown animated bounceInUp" ng-src="{{image.url}}" alt="{{image.id}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

- as well as my new 'showThis' function. the page works as I would like it to, but only if I double click each button.

```
    $scope.showThis = function (index){
    if(index!==$scope.nowShowing){
      $scope.nowShowing=null;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.nowShowing = index;
        $scope.images[Math.abs(index-1)].set = 'off'
                $scope.images[index].set = 'on'
      }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Or make a jsFiddle?

Comment: I edited above to show some of my code.  I think that if I could move the current picture to the back, so the next image to be displayed was layed on top of it, I would have no problem.  Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this because I'm facing same issue. If I make the animation faster, screen paints faster but no real solution. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the OP, I fixed it in my case like this:

**Problematic Code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="formMenu.$invalid" ng-click="saveMenu('UPDATE', menu.id, formMenu.$valid);">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="!ajaxCalls.isInProgress('saveRestaurantMenuDetails' + menu.id)"></span>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin-animate" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="ajaxCalls.isInProgress('saveRestaurantMenuDetails' + menu.id)"></span>
                                        </button>
```

**Fixed Code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="formMenu.$invalid" ng-click="saveMenu('UPDATE', menu.id, formMenu.$valid);">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-floppy-disk': !ajaxCalls.isInProgress('saveRestaurantMenuDetails' + menu.id), 'glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin-animate' : ajaxCalls.isInProgress('saveRestaurantMenuDetails' + menu.id) }"></span>
                                        </button>
```

So basically have two different SPANs and showing them mutually exclusive, I put the ng-class on the single SPAN and that seems to fix the issue even when its animating. I'm sure, it is still causing delay due to animation but hey, at least I don't see two image where only one icon should show at a time.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to see exactly what your problem is, but based on your description, it sounds like you actually need to set both images to hidden to allow for the transition to complete and then set the next image in a timeout.  Here is a working plunker using angular-motion for the animations.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oDARTE67Iqkdm81mT1RG

As for your button not displaying the expected image, I'd need to see your code to provide a solution.

Comment: The button does in fact display the correct image, it is just initially covered by the old image.  I will try your solution asap, thank you for the suggestion; i added my html above.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.